# I am getting 0 prodcut price whwn I add in my Cart fro admin panel

Tags: magento2, checkout, admin, cart, price

[image]

Whenever i am trying to add product in cart from admin panel its getting 0. I don't know why because it was working fine earlier.

Comment: bcoz, you have some customization that this happen , disable custom modules one by one  and check what happen

Comment: Thank you for your response Amit. But in my another store view it is working fine. I m getting price in my cart.